# How can I resolve this problem with dataloaders?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I'm building some dataloaders for training and testing a machine learning model.
I have a list of tuples named "array" like this:

```
(Data(x=[468, 2], edge_index=[2, 1322], y=0, edge_weight=[1322]), 'morphed_img027485_img054553.png')
(Data(x=[468, 2], edge_index=[2, 1322], y=0, edge_weight=[1322]), 'morphed_img031737_img054553.png')
```

I create the dataloader like this:

```
data_loader = create_dataloader(array, batch_size=60)
save_dataloader(data_loader, 'NameofDataLoader')
```

The output is not what I expect but it combines all the data into a single DataBatch, as shown below:

```
[DataBatch(x=[936, 2], edge_index=[2, 2644], y=[2], edge_weight=[2644], batch=[936], ptr=[3]), ('morphed_img031737_img054553.png', 'morphed_img027485_img054553.png')]
```

Why? How can I have a dataloader with all the data separated like in the array?

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over this batched output, separating the `x`, `edge_index`, `y`, etc.? Or why the batched output is the shape it is (i.e. I'd expect  the file names to have `len` of 60 not 2 since batch size is 60). Can you include the code for the dataloaders?